# WinForms application self-recoverability (running a self-hosted WCF service)

Tags: winforms, wcf

I am about to deploy a thoroughly-tested, WinForms application running a self-hosted WCF service.

This is for a rather business-critical requirement, so I am concerned about self-recoverability.

What if it fails because of an unhandled exception? (Although all exception-catching mechanisms are in place, I do want to consider that possibility). Is there any recommended way to restart the application again? Much, much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using Windows Service,

since it already have a self-recover feature(auto restart).

Just take a look into this page: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/251192/en-us

, and this one: [sc.exe to install an exe as a service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15127513/sc-exe-to-install-an-exe-as-service)